# How to Claims Enable a Windows Service

Tags: .net, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs2.0, adfs2.1

The majority of samples I find regarding claims based security focus on a WCF or Web Application or perhaps OWIN or self-hosted Web API.

Assume the federation server is ADFS 2; how would a .Net application in the form of a Windows service authenticate to ADFS, receive claims and take appropriate action? How would said service / application identify itself to ADFS in order to be trusted?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Probably with WS-Trust or something. Search for WIF Samples and that should filter out the OWIN Identity stuff.

Comment: That's not the right question to ask - you are asking about the host - you should first ask about the communication technology. A Windows Service could use WCF or Web API. What do you want to use?